# tif Linux tcp server compiled by g++ doesn't work

Tags: linux, gcc, tcp, g++

am trying to run tcp server on Linux Mint ( 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux ).

Here is my code:

```
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <time.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        char sendBuff[1025];
        time_t ticks;
        listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
        memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

        if ( bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0 ) {
        return 0;
         }
        if ( listen(listenfd, 10) < 0 ) { 
        return 0;
         }

        while(1)
        {
            connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
            ticks = time(NULL);

            snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
            write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));

            close(connfd);
        }
    }
```

When its compiled with :

```
gcc tcp-server.cpp -g -o tcpserver
```

and tested with

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5000
```

everything is ok and message looks like this

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Sun Feb 22 21:39:51 2015
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But when I do the same with g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

```
g++ tcp-server.cpp -g -o tcpserver
```

I get

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

There are no errors in socket,bind,listen functions. Application calls accept() function correctly and waits infinitely.

So I have tried older g++-4.7 and result is the same. In g++-4.6 doesn't work as well. The only thing I've notices that only working version of g++ is 4.6 but without "-g" flag.

```
g++-4.6 tcp-server.cpp -o tcpserver
```

What to do? Reinstall something? Additional packages necessary? All gcc/g++ 4.6 and 4.7 downloaded from Linux Mint - Software Manager application. 4.8 was preinstalled.

--
EDIT: if statements added to bind() and listen() but doesn't help

Comment: Check the return values for `bind` and `listen`.

Comment: I thought  about it and checked before, but unfortunetly it is not solving anything.Also tested in debugger and gdb enters() accept correcly

Comment: Use `perror` on failure of syscalls like `bind`, `listen`, `socket`, etc etc.... Read [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) about `SO_REUSEADDR`